# Проблема не могу вытщить get запросом один элеменет в масиве

Tags: reactjs, json, frontend

```
 "apartment_images": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "image": "https://vm4506017.43ssd.had.wf/media/apartment/image_rv_seven.png",
                    "created_at": "2023-06-20 18:34:33",
                    "apartment": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "image": "https://vm4506017.43ssd.had.wf/media/apartment/image_rv_six.png",
                    "created_at": "2023-06-20 18:34:19",
                    "apartment": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "image": "https://vm4506017.43ssd.had.wf/media/apartment/image_rv_three.png",
                    "created_at": "2023-06-20 18:33:57",
                    "apartment": 2
                }
            ],
```

вот так выглядит массив

```js
  async function getProducts() {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/apartment/`);
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.products,
        payload: data.results,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

функция стягивания
`<img src={item.apartment_images.image} alt="error" />`
и вот сюда нужно стянуть изображение но я щас не понимаю как это сделать всю ночь просидел все перебрал не получлось помогите срочно

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы получили массив и сохранили его в глобальном `store` с помощью `dispatch`.
2. Затем вам необходимо в компоненте, где у вас этот тег `img` вызвать хук `useSelector`, который позволяет получить глобальные объекты из store.
3. Через `useSelector` получаете данный массив в свой компонент и либо по индексу, либо же, если у вас этих тегов `img` несколько, с помощью `map` в `img` передаете значение ключа `image` из вашего массива.

Answer (score 0):

```
{item.apartment_images.length > 0 ? (
  <img
    width="100%"
    src={item.apartment_images[0].image}
    alt="error"
  />
) : (
  <p>No image available.</p>
)}
```

решилось таким образом, нужно было длину убрать, и потом по идексу первый